# What is wrong with this GFCI outlet?

Tags: gfci, testing

I have a GFCI outlet which is testing wierdly.  On one of the plugs, one prong tests hot and the other does not (using a Voltaware).  On the other plug, both prongs test hot.  The other outlets on the same circuit test fine.  I reversed the black and white wires and nothing changed.  Any ideas?  Will replacing the GFCI outlet resolve the problem?

Comment: Turn the breaker off, open it up, and take a picture of both sides and the back.  Maybe there's something we can see.  Also, are you using a multimeter or a non-contact voltage tester, like Steven mentioned?  It could be a few different things.

Answer (score 5):

A non-contact tester might give you a false-positive on the neutral in some cases.  Try testing the outlet with an outlet tester which will indicate if the hot/neutral are switched or open.  Alternatively you can use a multi-meter to test it.  If you are in the US, you should get ~120VAC between hot and neutral, but 0VAC between neutral and ground if the outlet is wired correctly.

[image: Outlet Tester]